# How to overwrite next line after found line in text document

Tags: c#

here I want one thing, so I take line from some value, found it in text document and now I want overwrite X not over the found line, but over the next line coming after this found line

so if content is:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

and if `string text = "line2";` with this code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace _03_0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "line2";

            string text = File.ReadAllText("doc.txt"); 
            text = text.Replace(text, "X"); 
            File.WriteAllText("doc.txt", text);          
        }
    }
}
```

I have this result:

```
line1
X
line3
line4
```

but I want this result:

```
line1
line2 
X
line4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
string filePath = @"doc.txt";
string myStr = "line2";
string content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<={0}\r\n).+?(?=\r\n)", myStr);
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
File.WriteAllText(filePath, r.Replace(content, "X"));
```

P.S: you'll need to import `RegularExpressions` namespace:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Hope that helps :)

**A side note**: *You can't use the same variable name (`text`) twice.*

Comment: @zrubi if the line contains any of those characters `\*+?|{[()^$.# ` you have to escape it with [`Regex.Escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape). For example: `string pattern = string.Format(@"(?<={0}\r\n).+?(?=\r\n)", Regex.Escape(myStr));`

Comment: Not debating the efficacy, but this is all that comes to mind [Regex: now you have 2 problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate over your lines.
Once you found your line, read the next one and change it.

```
// pseudo code:
var all_text = File.ReadAllLines("doc.txt"); 
bool b = false;
for (var s in all_text)
{
   // add s to a list of strings

   if (b)
   {
      // add the new string to the list
      b = false;
   }
   if (/* s == match */ )
     b = true;
}

// write your file.
```

this will add all the lines, and change the next one to what you want, and then add all the rest.
make sure you write the file at the end.

Comment: I think it should be ReadAllLines() instead of ReadAllText().

Comment: Yep ... since it returns an array of strings ... As top said, mainly pseudocode with a direction to follow

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the line to change the line after it:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("doc.txt");
int i = Array.IndexOf(lines, "line2");
if (i >= 0 && i < lines.Length - 1)
{
    lines[i + 1] = "X";
    File.WriteAllLines("doc.txt", lines);
}
```

Comment: Yes useful as it is, but I what avoid this way for actual case